# How can I toggle grey-out the arrows to enhance my carousel UI experience?

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I have a bunch of boxes slide-able in a carousel like this :

[image]

Here is the structure of my divs:

```
<ul>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">1</div></li>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">2</div></li>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">3</div></li>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">4</div></li>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">5</div></li>
    <li class="mp-resource"><div class="tl-box">6</div></li>
</ul>
```

When my page load, I can't scroll to the left, so I want to grey-out my left arrow. I don't want to confuse my user.

[image]

In addition to that, I want to grey out my right arrow when my I can't scroll the right anymore.

[image]

What is the most efficient way to achieve something like that ?

How can I check to see if I am at the end of my carousel ?

Here is my live result : [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/e9L60rfr/)

Comment: First of all, try to calculate a grid for your elements. Then, move the carousel content by steps (each step is x * (element width), where x is how many items you would like to scroll). That way, you could easily calculate how many items you have scrolled, and then check how much are left to be scrolled.

Comment: Wow, it sound complicated. Can you help me with the starter code or something in jQuery ?

Comment: Further, please reduce your code to the absolute minimum to reproduce your problem; and include that (minimal) code in the question itself.

Comment: you need to apply some CSS classes to a common container upon setting the scroll. then you can use ex: `.container._0_5 .btnLeft{ opacity: 0.5; pointer-events: none; }` to "disable" the button, where `0` is the index and `5` is the max

Comment: @dandavis : +1 ... Can you please add your suggestion in my fiddle instead ?

Comment: @rangerover.js what would your grid be? Have you decided?

Comment: I don't know how to do that man. I'm sorry. I know the width and the height and that's about it. I also know that I have 6 divs, and each div is store in an `li` and they are the child of `ul`. Grid ? I'm a little lost.

Comment: here is a start, you need to do the right arrow, and switch from `title` to `data-title`  https://jsfiddle.net/e9L60rfr/15/

Comment: The movement works fine, or am I looking at a different fiddle? Isn't it just the arrow state that is the problem here? I don't see why you would want to add a grid or anything, but perhaps I am missing something here...

Comment: @Pevara: I'm very confuse about that grid suggestion, too. I just want to change the color of my arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should detect if you are at the left or at the right after each scroll animation, and then change state of the arrow buttons accordingly. The check would be done by checking the scroll position and probably look something like this:

```
    function isLeft() { 
         return $scrollView.scrollLeft() == 0;   
    }
    function isRight() {
         return $overflow.width() - $carousel.width() - $scrollView.scrollLeft() <= 0;    
    }
```

The isLeft() function just checks if the we are scrolled entirely to the left, or the scrollLeft is 0. That one should be easy.

The isRight() basically says [width of the entire scrollable area] - [width of the part off the scrollable area that is visible] - [the amount the scrollable area is scrolled to the left]. If that becomes equal to 0 we can say we are scrolled entirely to the end. There is not much to explain here, it is basic math.

For the button state, I would use the jQuery [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function together with the 2 helper functions I just showed you, to add a `disabled` attribute to your buttons when required, or remove it when no longer required. Something like this:

```
 $leftArrow.attr('disabled', isLeft());
 $rightArrow.attr('disabled', isRight());
```

For the css part, you can use the attribute selector `[disabled]`. Something like this:

```
.mp-arrows[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    color: #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

And the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9L60rfr/16/

Note that I also added the disabled attribute to the left button in your HTML, since on load you will always be scrolled to the left, and this way you do not need the run the checks on load.

Comment: How do I do that in console ? I'm pretty new to all of this. I hope you don't mind. Should I do something like this `console.log(isLeft())` ?

Comment: I know where it is, I just don't know, how to test your solution, and add a class to it  ?

Comment: Do you mind add a little more details on how to test your suggested function on the console? I'm sure this will means alot to noobie like me. Also, I know how to use jQuery to add a class , but with your solution, what should be my **selector** ? Please add a little more instruction in the bottom of your answer, I will make sure to accept it. You're pretty close.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your precisely answer. You're awesome !